# How would you go about graphing a set of points (x,y) that satisfies the following equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Could you explain how this is different from graphing any other equation? 
What confuses me is that there are two y-values and two x-values.

The equation is: y+|y| = x+|x|

Comment: Hint: Try rewriting the equation as $y-x = \mid x \mid - \mid y\mid$

Do you see why both $x$ and $y$ are both zero or both negative?

Answer (score 1):

Split it into four equations:

$y,x \geq 0 \implies 2y =2x \implies y=x$

$x \leq 0 \leq y \implies 2y=0 \implies y=0$.

$y \leq 0 \leq x \implies 2x=0 \implies x=0$.

$y,x \leq 0 \implies 0=0$, so here this is true for all values of $x$ and $y$.

Hence, we take the graphs of these four functions and combine them to get the solution set:
$$
S = \{ y \leq 0 ,x \leq 0\} \cup \{ y =0\} \cup \{x=0\} \cup \{x=y\}
$$
The second and third set absorb into the first, so the answer would be:
$$
S = \{ y \leq 0 ,x \leq 0\} \cup \{x=y\}
$$

Hence $|x| + x = |y| + y$ if and only if $(x,y) \in S$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what is $x+|x|$ when $x<0$?

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyse this cases:

1. y>= 0, x >= 0
   Here you have equation y + y = x + x, that is 2y = 2x, y = x. You draw this only in the first quadrant.
2. y >= 0, x < 0
   Here you have equation y + y = x - x, that is 2y = 0, y = 0. You draw this only in the second quadrant (it is negative X axis)
3. y < 0, x >=0
   y - y = x + x, 0 = 2x, x = 0. You draw this in fourth quadrant, it is negative Y axis
4. y < 0, x < 0
   y - y = x - x , 0 = 0. You have to color whole third quadrant, without the axes.

Comment: $0=0$ being always true, you have to draw this ! (or color it)

Comment: This was really helpful. So anytime you have two y-values in an equation and you're asked to graph it, would you begin by splitting it up?

Comment: That is what you usually do when you have to deal with absolute values,  remove all absolute values and then work with a few simple (in)equations. And @Evariste is right, you will need to color the third quadrant. I will edit my post.